# Data attribute with variable not working with link_to rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, custom-data-attribute

I have many anchors in my page, and each one of them is related to a specific form.

So in each of the rails helper `link_to`, i want to add a specific data-form attribute as following:

```
link_to "Click here!", "#", data: { :form => "form-#{increment}"}
```

This line of code is not working and gives the following error :

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
```

Any clues how to fix this error ?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me, off the bat. #1 are you sure that's where the error is occuring? #2 does it make a difference if you include the parentheses around the `link_to` parameters (so `link_to("Click here!", "#"....`)?

Comment: Can you post your full helper method and also try `link_to "Click here!", "#","data-form" => "form-#{increment}"`

Comment: My bad guys !! i used increment instead of @increment! Thanks for your suggestions that helped find the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The `increment` method is already part of ActiveSupport/ActiveRecord: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment

It expects an `attribute` argument which you are not providing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nevertheless, i get the same error if i replace it with something else ( data: { :form => "form-#{test}"} ) and "test" is not empty!

Comment: The problem was as simple as using increment instead of @increment !

Comment: Good eyes, didn't see that, however that method only takes 2 arguments, there's no optional 3rd argument, so it wouldn't produce that exact error message (the `2..3` part).